# Load data from database without refreshing the page using vue.js and php

Tags: php, mysqli, vue.js

Im trying to make a comment section where people comment and that comment have to be inserted into my database and then shown in my page.
I already insert it without refreshing page.

But when i want the comment to load without refreshing the page, I can't.

This is my select code where i select the comments i want but it needs to reload the page in order to see it

```
<?php
$slug2 = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM comments where slug = '$slug2'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

$comment = $row['comment'];
$the_datetime = $row['datetime'];
$userid_comment = $row['userid'];

$query_image = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users where id = '$userid_comment'");
$row =  mysqli_fetch_array($query_image);
$image = $row['image'];
$name_comment = $row['profilename'];
$username_comment = $row['username'];

    // SELECT COMMENTS
    echo"<div class=\"comment\">
      <div class=\"comment-avatar\">";
      if($image == "") {
        echo"
        <a href=\"/user/$username_comment\"><img class=\"mobilecommentimage\" style=\"object-fit:cover\" src=\"/img/change-user.png\"></a>";
      }
      else{
        echo"
        <a href=\"/user/$username_comment\"><img class=\"mobilecommentimage\" style=\"object-fit:cover\" src=\"$image\"></a>";
      }
        echo"
      </div>

      <div class=\"comment-box\">
        <div style=\"line-height:20px;font-weight:700;font-size:17px\"><a href=\"/user/$username_comment\" style=\"color:#428bca\">$name_comment</a></div>
        <div style=\"line-height:20px\" class=\"comment-text\">$comment</div>
        <div class=\"comment-footer\">
          <div class=\"comment-info\">
            <span style=\"line-height:18px\" class=\"comment-date\">$the_datetime</span>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    ";}

     ?>
```

Basically what i want is to select comments and load them into my page without refreshing the page using php and vue.js

Please i need some help. Thanks everybody.

Comment: As your data is comming from PHP it's impossible. You need Vue to talk to your PHP like its an API. Then with Vue you can fetch the data every time you edited the data. This way the page won't reload to a user only the data is rerendered

Comment: you are right! you recommend me vue components and template?

Comment: You just need to seperate the logic of Vue and PHP

Comment: Yes, you were right